# Dynamic SQL queries

Tags: sql, select, dynamic

I want to find values from one table to another table but dynamically. Ex. my table has 2 columns. One column stores the value as below. I want to create dynamic SQL that takes the data from column A and find in ColumnB.

```
Column1       Column2
02/28/2019    2017-07-15^2018-07-15^2019-07-15^2020-07-15 ^ 2019-02-28
```

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result. Take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your Logic correct then try this Query...

```
SELECT id,Status1 FROM tbl t1
WHERE STATUS1='D'
AND EXISTS 
( 
SELECT id,Status2 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.Status1=t2.Status2
)
```

Note : - Suppose, you have a have Called Tbl, it Contains Column(id,Status1,Status2)

> then you have to select (Status1) from tbl t1  and check with same
>   table with Column (Status2) checking with exists Query...

So,You can check Status1 Column value with Status2 Column in same table...